# Can't Use Variables in mysql_query()?

Tags: php, mysql

This is about as basic as it gets guys and girls.

I have a very simple script that just will not work.  I call the database and test it's connection, I do a query, store the result, and print the result.

The problem is that I can't seem to use any variables in my SQL statement.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

    $rest_name = $_GET['rest_name']; // outputs 'Starbucks'

    $test = mysql_query("SELECT code_id FROM table_code WHERE restaurant = '$rest_name'");

    /* I've also tried these as well
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT code_id FROM table_code WHERE restaurant = '".$rest_name."'");
    */

    $mark = mysql_result($test,0);

    echo $_GET['rest_name'].$mark; 
?>
```

I echoed the query and it looks fine and run fine in the database.  The $rest_name variable echos fine.  The $_GET['rest_name'] echos fine.  I am lost and confused on this.

Comment: What happens when you try it? Do you get an error? Nothing at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Also, you **are** connecting to the database before you try to query it, right?

Comment: You're using a variable directly from $_GET in the query?  Your database will get owned very quickly if you put that code on a public website.  Also, mysql_* is obsolete, you really shouod be using mysqli or pdo instead

Comment: I am switching to mysqli. I posted the connection to show that I am connecting to the database and I did test for connection prior to querying.  It's very basic. I should have mentioned that this is within a Wordpress install and the global $wpdb is not working for this page, that is, any query that has a variable in it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can start with this.

```
$test = mysql_query("S....") or die(mysql_error());
```

This way you will see what error you are getting.

2 - you might want to avoid using a variable provided by the user in your query

```
$rest_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rest_name']);
```

otherwise user can insert their own sql commands;

3 - mysql_xxx functions are being deprecated, you might want to research pdo or mysqli to see how the new methods work.

Comment: You might also want to not use `mysql_*` altogether :)

Comment: I did that, and no error can up. It I placed a random value to replace the variable I get a result fine.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have a valid result set returned by msyql_query

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT ... ");
if (!$test) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

(It's possible you aren't connected to the MySQL instance, you are in the wrong database, the user you are connected as doesn't have permissions, etc.)

Check the resultset, before you use it.

---

**NOTE:** Don't use the mysql_ functions, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: The `mysql_query` function shouldn't even be discussed. It should be for legacy applications *only*.